# fs.readFile and variable passing in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have two variables like this  in my node project

```
header ="Hello Header";
result =  `<html>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div class='modal'>
                <div class='header'>
                    ${header}
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>`;
```

I want to load this html part from an html file and pass the **header** value on to it. How we can achieve it ?

I know we can use fs.readFile

```
fs.readFile("index.html", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    result = data;
});
```

But how can I pass the **header** variable into this ?

Comment: Pass `header` where? What are you trying to accomplish? What is the desired result? What exactly should happen with the loaded HTML? `header` is already inserted into the `result` string; what else do you need to do with it? Please [edit] and clarify your question.

Comment: Is this [yet another duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)?

Comment: create a placeholder string in the html file and once load the html file then replace the pace holder string with `header` variable value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and fastest solution would be to:

- make the replaceable header part in the HTML discoverable with a
  pattern like {{ header }}
- read the file as you would normally

  fs.readFile("index.html", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  // make something here
  });

OR

you could use promises for better readability and compact code

```
import {promises} from "fs"
(async () => {
  const html = await promises.readFile(file, "utf8");
})()
```

- then when you have the HTML in a variable just do:

  data.replace("{{ header }}", header)

Comment: let me check bro

Comment: data is the html variable in the promises example